# Ionic 5 default tab project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I created new default tab project . I changed nothing. run the ionic  serve no errors app opened in beowser its empty nothing.

After long investgation i found it opens the index.html inside src.

what happend why it is not lunching the real app.

I have ionic 5

Comment: Your issue is not clear.. index.html is what is supposed to be loaded.. It is supposed to be Single Page Application.. Can you post any error that you see in your developer console..

Comment: how are you running your project? it should be via terminal with `ionic serve` command

Answer (score 0):

It was a chrom problem. I had old version I upgrade it works fine. Looks old chrom dont understand type="model" for that it was nit downloading the js file